# Dealing with a large string containing apostrophes SQL

Tags: java, sql

Now I am having an issue where trying to insert some info into a database is giving me a SQLException: General Error. I have determined the issue is that my string has apostrophes in it. Here is my update statement:

```
AniDB.updateTbl("UPDATE SeriesTbl SET SeriesSynopsis = '" + synop + "' WHERE  SeriesID = " + sID);
```

SeriesSynopsis contains many records, all with different strings. Let's say for sake of argument, one record is "Tom doesn't like cats" and another is "Timothy couldn't care less about cats." The apostrophes are in different positions and are interfering with my SQL Statement. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
AniDB.updateTbl("UPDATE SeriesTbl SET SeriesSynopsis = '" + synop.replace("'", "''") + "' WHERE  SeriesID = " + sID);
```

You can escape a quote with 2 quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this page: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Beyond solving your immediate problem, learning to use prepared statements will make your code far less vulnerable, can simplify your code and make it more portable and can improve the efficiency of your database.  I would regard the SQL Injection issue as urgent... well worth the time spent.